# Datatable columndefs not being hit

Tags: javascript, datatable

I have been trying to render my json in datatable. The json format i have been working with is as follows:

```
{
   message: "",
   data: {
      count: "",
      result: [
          {
             parameter1: "",
             parameter2: "",
             parameter3: "",
          },
          {
             parameter1: "",
             parameter2: "",
             parameter3: "",
          },
      ]
   }
}
```

Datatable Code is as follow

```
$('#example').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            url: "https://c22c6e75-a9b9-4762-8f5d-b25137536fa6.mock.pstmn.io/iprSearchData",
        },
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [0],
                "data": function (row, type, val, meta) {
                    // not hitting
                    console.log(row);
                    console.log(type);
                    console.log(val);
                    console.log(meta);
                },
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(row);
                    return data;
                },
            },
            // {targets: [0], visible: true},
            // {targets: '_all', visible: false}
        ]
    });
```

I read the documentation and I assume the data(JSON) format is creating problems for me in rendering or is it some other issue?
I want to render my parameters in reult array of the JSON to be displayed in a single column.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON format was the issue. Use datasrc in ajax for appropriate data from the returned ajax.